# GET request with @RequestBody annotation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

Can we use `GET` request with `@RequestBody` annotation in Spring mvc or not?

I am not able to understand why it is working with `POST` and not `GET`.
Also in the spring-reference.pdf the use of this annotation is with `PUT`.

Can someone please explain can it be used with other `RequestMethods` as well and how to use the same.

Comment: Probably your client or something at a lower tier in the server is ignoring or stripping it.  Adding a body to a GET is technically not forbidden by HTTP, but it's sort of undefined and not universally supported.

Comment: and what about "PUT". Can i use it with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your client or something at a lower tier in the server is ignoring or stripping it. Adding a body to a GET is technically not forbidden by HTTP, but it's sort of undefined and not universally supported.